# Finding a table row that matches the text in a cell with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

If would like to access the row element from a HTML table where the text in a certain cell matches my string `'Mathematik & Informatik'`.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="views-table cols-4">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek" scope="col">
            Teilbibliothek          
         </th>
         <th class="views-field views-field-field-tag" scope="col">
            Datum          
         </th>
         <th class="views-field views-field-field-zeitslot" scope="col">
            Zeitraum          
         </th>
         <th class="views-field views-field-views-conditional" scope="col">
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="odd views-row-first">
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek">
            Stammgelände          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-tag">
            <span class="date-display-single">Samstag, 22. Januar 2022</span>          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-zeitslot">
            09:00 – 14:30          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-views-conditional internlink">
            ausgebucht          
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek">
            Stammgelände          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-tag">
            <span class="date-display-single">Samstag, 22. Januar 2022</span>          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-zeitslot">
            15:00 – 21:30          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-views-conditional internlink">
            ausgebucht          
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek">
            Mathematik &amp; Informatik          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-tag">
            <span class="date-display-single">Samstag, 22. Januar 2022</span>          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-zeitslot">
            10:00 – 14:30          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-views-conditional internlink">
            ausgebucht          
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek">
            Mathematik &amp; Informatik          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-tag">
            <span class="date-display-single">Samstag, 22. Januar 2022</span>          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-zeitslot">
            15:00 – 19:30          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-views-conditional internlink">
            ausgebucht          
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek">
            Weihenstephan          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-tag">
            <span class="date-display-single">Samstag, 22. Januar 2022</span>          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-zeitslot">
            10:00 – 14:30          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-views-conditional internlink">
            <a href="/reserve/1438527699">Zur Reservierung</a>          
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even views-row-last">
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek">
            Weihenstephan          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-tag">
            <span class="date-display-single">Samstag, 22. Januar 2022</span>          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-field-zeitslot">
            15:00 – 19:30          
         </td>
         <td class="views-field views-field-views-conditional internlink">
            <a href="/reserve/530262745">Zur Reservierung</a>          
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using Python and Selenium and came up with the following bit of code to get the table row I want.

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table//tr/td[contains(text(),'Mathematik & Informatik')]/..")
```

This line returns a list with three elements. These are the two rows that match my string `'Mathematik & Informatik'`, but also another element that somehow has the text `' Mathematik & Informatik, Weihenstephan  8:00 – 14:3015:00 – 21:30 10:00 – 14:3015:00 – 19:30 '`.

I do not understand what's wrong with my XPATH (why It does not return only the two rows with the given text). Could you help me fix it please?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The HTML that you've shared only shows 2 matching nodes. Is that the entire HTML ?

Comment: You are right, see the comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not agree with the @Prophet solution, since there are **trailing spaces** and if you do not use `.contains` it won't match up any node.

I see only two matching nodes in the HTML that you've shared. However, you can make it tightly coupled with class like this:

```
//table//tr/td[contains(text(),'Mathematik & Informatik') and @class='views-field views-field-field-teilbibliothek']
```

also, Selenium does not have support for XPath v2.0, if it had, we'd have ended up using `ends-with`.

to remove **trailing spaces**, please use:

```
//table//tr/td[normalize-space()='Mathematik & Informatik']/..
```

You will have to check-in **HTMLDOM** first that how many nodes it is **matching**:

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `elements` is getting **highlighted** with `1/2` matching node.

Comment: You are right. I checked and the third match come from another table on the same webpage, which contains these elements. You're solution returns only the matches that I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to match lines with text **equals** to some value, not just **contains** some text (and may contain additional text there) you should use appropriate XPath expression.
So, instead of

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table//tr/td[contains(text(),'Mathematik & Informatik')]/..")
```

You can use

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table//tr/td[text()='Mathematik & Informatik']/..")
```

BTW, you can also locate the desired `tr` element directly, without a need to step up from the `td` as following:

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table//tr[./td[text()='Mathematik & Informatik']]")
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I believe the text attributes contains spaces, such that checking for the equality does not find any element.

Comment: Well, if you were sharing a link to that page I could give a better answer. In retrospect I agree with cruisepanda's solution here